# How to call function from another function using magento knockout js?

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs, knockout

I need quick help regarding calling a function within a function using Magento knockout js, I have tried this

```
define([
    'ko',
    'uiComponent'
], function (ko, Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            //initialize parent Component
            this._super();
        },

        testfunctionout: function() {
        var self = this;
            console.log(' in testfunctionout');
        self.testfunctionin();
        },

        testfunctionin: function() {
            console.log(' in testfunctionin');
        }

    });
});
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error you got in console? Did you called `testfunctionout` function?

Answer (score 2):

use self under initailize function dont declare it under testfunctionOut

```
 initialize: function () {
            self = this;
 }
 testfunctionout: function() {
        console.log(' in testfunctionout');
    self.testfunctionin();
    },

    testfunctionin: function() {
        console.log(' in testfunctionin');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
define([
    'ko',
    'uiComponent'
], function (ko, Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            //initialize parent Component
            var self = this;
            this._super();
        },

        testfunctionout: function() {
            console.log('in testfunctionout');
            this.testfunctionin();
        },

        testfunctionin: function() {
            console.log(' in testfunctionin');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: this is not working while calling click function in knockout js

Comment: Can you please let me know in detail about click function or Post different question for the same.

Comment: I raised a  new query , https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/297222/how-to-call-a-function-inside-click-action-function-using-magento-knockout-js . Please let me know your feedback.